# two different warning, debugging messages from a series of build attempts

Tags: c, printf, eclipse-cdt, strlen

I am using Eclipse IDE and learning C with it. with the code below I get two different debugging messages from the first build and the second build.

```
char text2[]="I am a string!";
puts(text2);
printf("%d\n", strlen(text2));
```

in the console view of the first build,

- `21:46:32 Build Finished. 0 errors, 1 warnings. (took 1s.182ms)`
- with warning message hover next to the line numbers: `format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long' [-Wformat]`

Then, in the console view of the second build,

- `21:49:07 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 79ms)`
- runs fine and the hover message does not show up.

This behavior keeps showing up, which is not clear if it's from the IDE or the others.

Comment: Try compiling your program on command line. That will show if the messages come from the compiler. The warning is clearly comming from the compiler. `strlen` does not return an `int` but `size_t`. The correct format specifier for that is `%zu`.

Comment: Most likely the compiler is called with different options when compiling from the IDE and when compiling from the console. The IDE probably has a configuration window where the compiler options/flags are set. Find that window and use exactly the same options in the command view-

Comment: Which compiler do you use? -- The second build will not repeat the compilation, because you did not change the erroneous source. And so there is no (new) warning. -- The warning is not only shown if you hover over the erroneous line with the error marker, but should be visible in the console, too.

Comment: Please go through [format specifiers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/format-specifiers-in-c).

Comment: It is not building the second time round - it has already been built so it doesn't do anything - that is why it only took 79ms.  You need to clean first then build.  The warning is in the compilation.